# Combine with() and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use the 'with()' function from base R and I am wondering whether it can be combined with 'ggplot2'. If I use base plot I do:

```
df <- data.frame(a= 1:10, b= 1:10)

with(df, plot(a, b))
```

Analog approach with ggplot fails:

```
library(ggplot2)
with(df, {ggplot(aes(a, b)) + geom_point()})
```

I guess this is because 'with()' simply replaces 'plot(a, b)' to 'plot(df$a, df$b)' but 'ggplot()' does not work if we do not provide a data argument (at least not in this way). Is this right or can we somehow use 'with' and 'ggplot2' together?

---

Some comments ask why I want to do this and here is why. I am writing a quite general function that includes with() and I put varuous functions in with(), like mean(), sd() amd so on. ggplot() is just another function that I want to succesfuly put trough my function which includes knowing how to put ggplot() in with(). So far, my function could output dataframes and other objects, now I know how to put ggplot objects through my function. I did not include this in my question to keep it simple.

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to use `with()` here. `ggplot` already has a a parameter for you to pass in the data.frame where value are coming from. What do you think you can do with `with()` that you can't do with `ggplot()` alone?

Comment: If you are worried about the stability of the tidyverse packages then you should use a solution like `renv` or `packrat` to maintain a stable environment rather than constraining yourself to use `with`

Comment: Also if you're concerned about package stability, the main API of ggplot2 (`ggplot(data, aes(x, y))`) has been unchanged for many years now and will almost certainly never change. The modern idioms of R development rely on the style of evaluation that ggplot uses, completely supplanting the use of `with()`, which I haven't used in 6 or 7 years.

Comment: @MrFlick I write a function that includes with() and can put many objects though it. So, for examle I can put a data.frame though my function and get the desired output data. This is not possible with ggplot because the output is not a dataframe but a plot. The nice thing is that now my function can output various objects, including ggplot.

Comment: @Richard You are maybe right if we talk about the question as it stands, but in fact I am building a quite general function that includes with(). The function can output various objects and it works great so far. I do not know whether the alternatives you suggest work in my context.

Comment: @Brian No, I am not worried about the first arguments of ggplot() to change. I want to use with() in a general function that does things like applying functions by group and so on. My function uses with() and it outputs various objects. I do not want to include something from tidyverse like group_by(), mutate() and so on in my function.

Comment: @Drumy Thanks. Plus the circumstance that the approach maybe even is inline with common thinking if I would share the whole usecase. I put all kind of functions in with() in my code, mean(), sd(), ... ggplot() is just another one which now I can pass though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the first argument of `ggplot()` is `data`. You need to specifically say that you want to use the argument `mapping`.

```
df <- data.frame(a= 1:10, b= 1:10)
with(df, ggplot(mapping = aes(a, b)) + geom_point())
```

Or you can do this

```
df <- data.frame(a= 1:10, b= 1:10)
with(df, ggplot() + geom_point(aes(a, b))
```

The second method works because the first argument for `geom_*` is `mapping`.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(a, b)) + geom_point()
```

[image: ggplot2]

Comment: Thank you. Please see my edit: My question is now more explicitly about the with() function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `qplot()` which is designed to be similar to the base `plot()` syntax, and its `data` argument is not necessary.

```
library(ggplot2)
with(df, { qplot(a, b) + geom_point() })
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `%>%`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
    ggplot(aes(a, b)) + 
           geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you I am aware of dplyr solutions but I want to avoid using it because I am afraid of changes in the packages. Therefore I try to use more base functions which are supposed to be more stable over time. At the moment I am getting used to with().